# How to correctly use iterrows in a DataFrame

Tags: python

I want to find out the highest price of a specified house type, "mansion". instead of using `df[df["h_type"] == "mansion"]["h_price"].max()` ， i want to try something new.

I use `iterrows()` method, but it does not work out as expected.

**First**, I defind a price function attempting to find out the highest price **(this works)**

```
def price():
    most=0
    priceSr=df['h_price'].str.replace(',','').astype('float')
    if not df.empty:
        idMax = priceSr.idxmax()
        if  not isnan(idMax): 
            maxSr = df.loc[idMax]
            if most is None:
            most = maxSr.copy()
            else:
            if float(maxSr['h_price']) > float(most['h_price']):
                most = maxSr.copy()

    most = most.to_frame().transpose()
    print(most, '\n==========')
```

**Secondly**, i narrow down to mansion under h_type  **(this work)**

```
mansion=df[df["h_type"].isin(["mansion"])]
mansion
```

**Finally,** i look up into "mansion" in second step, with price function. (**it does not work**, the result yields as if i have not look specifically into the second_step code mentioned above)

```py
for index, row in mansion.iterrows():
  price()
```

For another story, i try something new to replace the third step, it not yileds any results, instead gives an error message

```
mansion.apply(price,axis=1)
```

Error message

```
    826             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    827                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 828                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    829                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    830                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

TypeError: price() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Any advice concerning either codes will be appreciated.

Comment: `price()`, as written, works on the entire dataframe (with, it seems, a `df` reference to from an outer scope). So there's no reason to call it in a loop or use with any apply functions (which, speaking very loosely, assumes there will be something to apply to - a series or the values in a series).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to groupby each h_type and then get the max h_price like below.

```
df_grouped = df[['h_type','h_price'] ].groupby(['h_type']).max()
```